# Tutorial screens for app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Hi I have found an awesome tutorial to show an overview of my app. how would you return back to the main app after this tutorial view has been viewed?
Here is the location of the tutorial and all the [source code](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/).

My app views are in storyboard and I have a navigationcontroller in which my rootviewcontroller is held.
I'm hoping to return to the rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller after the last page of the tutorial view is displayed.
Thank you if you can help.

[image]

Here is my storyboard:
The code I used to load the tutorial is this in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     /*  This loads up the xib but I can't get back to the storyboard rootViewController */
    if (tutorialHasBeenSeen == false) {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.appViewController = [[APPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"APPViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.appViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        tutorialHasBeenSeen =TRUE;

    }


    return YES;
}
```

Would I try to pop to the rootView in the AppViewController.m in the method:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

    index++;

    if (index == 5) {
        return  nil;
    }
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

**EDIT**

Now that I see what you are trying to do, I would recommend changing your approach: 
Instead of choosing if you should present the **Tutorial** in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the  application delegate, why don't you always start on your application's **First** view controller, and here determine if the user should be displayed with a **Tutorial** or not, in that way you can invoke the **Tutorial** view controller inside your First view controller in your established navigation way of displaying hierarchical content.

[image]

The reason that you can't go from **Tutorial** to your **First** view controller is because you are assigning the **Tutorial** as your window view controller directly from the app delegate. So there is no way of going '*back*' from **Tutorial** to your **First** view controller, to fix this I can think on two options,

- At a desired moment change the window view controller of your application to be your **First** view controller instead of the already assigned **Tutorial** view controller. Which, as you may be guessing, is a tricky and just not clean way of doing this.
- Set up a proper navigation hierarchy in your app, so **First** view controller should present your **Tutorial** view controller. And after, at a desired moment you simply dismiss or pop your **Tutorial** and get back to your **First** view controller.

**As a conclusion,**

1.Don't present your Tutorial from the AppDelegate, so leave the following method clean or as necessary but to perform other actions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

2.From the view controller that will be your **First** view controller, invoke your Tutorial using [segues](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/performing-segues-in-ios-programmatically) or by [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) applying your desired logic for determining when a user should see the tutorial. If done properly when the app starts and the **Tutorial** appears it will be  invisible that you are first displaying the **First** view controller

3.From your **Tutorial** view controller and at the desired moment [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) or [pop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:) (will depend on your navigation) your view controller so you can go back to the **First** view controller

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure where to put that? I've tried a few places but it's not working.  Also to load the tutorial view have used the code from the view controller of the tutorial and loaded it via app delegate. Not sure if that's right either but the tutorial view is loading.

Comment: Ok I see, please put an image of your storyboard so I can understand better what is your current state. I have checked the tutorial and is not using storyboards so I can guess yours is slightly different.

Comment: @Coche how would I get the bool variable to just be set the one time the app is run? I've got in in viewdidlaunch but I know this is wrong. By the way thank you for,the above answer I managed to get it to work with some little work. (5 hours labour today).  You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Sure, You can have a boolean using [NSUserDefaults](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSUserDefaults.html). So whenever starting the app you will check for that value and see if the user has already gone through the tutorial or not. I'm glad it helped you